# Get float value out from NSDictionary

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, floating-point, xamarin

I'm seeking for a solution in `C#`. I have a dictionary like

```
NSDictionary metrics = new NSDictionary ("leftInset", 22);
```

Now I want to get the number as `float`. I tried this

```
metrics.ValueForKey(new NSString("leftInset"))
```

but the return value is of type `NSObject`. How can I get the float?

Comment: I am not a C# guy, but i believe there should be a method/function that converts it to float...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
float f = (metrics ["leftInset"] as NSNumber).FloatValue;
```

Answer (score 3):

Cast it to an [NSNumber](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aMonoTouch.Foundation.NSNumber).

[NSDictionary](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aMonoTouch.Foundation.NSDictionary):

There is a convenient constructor that takes at least one key and one value, with optional values that will create the dictionary by pairing each key with a value. If you use .NET objects, the keys and values will first be boxed into NSObjects using NSObject.FromObject.